# Hazelcast running aggregations in parallel with no executor config set

Tags: java, configuration, executorservice, hazelcast

With Hazelcast, I can run aggregation jobs using the imap.aggregate(...) method.  This method under the hood uses the IExecutorService and gives it a name based on the map your doing the aggregation on.

When I try and run aggregation jobs in parallel, I get a slew of RejectedExecutionExceptions.

I have found a workaround that works by specifically adding the ExecutorConfig for the map I am trying to aggregate against BEFORE I create my Hazelcast instance like so:

```
Config cfg = new Config();
....
ExecutorConfig execCfg = new ExecutorConfig("<exec_name_used_by_aggregate>");
cfg.addExecutorConfig(execCfg);
....
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
....
```

Now, this approach requires me to know the exact names for all the executors I will ever need while the Hazelcast instance is up and running because, if I am not mistaken, I cannot change the configuration of the instance while it is running, correct?  This approach also allows me to specify the thread pool size and queue size, but I also have to set them per ExecutionConfig before I start my instance.  That requires me to know the optimal number of threads needed before the instance is ever started/populated.

So, this brings me to some questions:

1. Is there any other way to get around the issue I am having?
2. Do I really need to explicitly add an ExecutorConfig for each ExecutorService I use?
3. Can I not add an ExecutorConfig after the instance is running?

Comment: Perhaps you could use wildcards in your configuration? See http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#using-wildcard

Comment: I have tried using wildcards, but they do not work.  Wildcards possibly might work if you do the following: `new ExecutorConfig("com.package.*")`, but I have not tried that.  The aggregate method names their executors like: `mapreduce::hz::hz::aggregation-map-<map_name>`.  I tried using a wildcard for the `<map_name>` part, but that did not work.